# Network Meter Accuracy

Tags: networking

MSN Network Meter
 I have the app on windows 7 desktop and am wondering how accurate it is.
Prime reason being, my ISP is claiming I have vastly larger data usage than the meter records.

Last month they said I had used my allocation when the meter said I had 10 of my 20Gb left.
Already this month the app says I've used 3.58, ISP claims 8.8Gb!!!

(Both sets of figures are for both upload and download).

Comment: Do you have more than one device, or do you have a WiFi access to your network that has no password?

Comment: What router do you have? Maybe it has a summary of data per period. (i know mine has.)